# Chatter group records - how can you remove them?

Tags: chatter

I am aware that you could add records to a Chatter group but I cannot see what benefits this would give users apart from having the record(s) conveniently placed in the Group page.

I have added an Account and a Contact record to a Chatter group but could not figure out how to remove them from the group ?! Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chatter Group Page
[image: Chatter Group page]

Look for "Group Records" CLick on "Show All".

Below pop up gets opened: Now Click on Remove button, Record will get removed from the Chatter Group.

[image: Record removal pop up]